# How do I create a line between two divs (or two points) in reactjs?

Tags: css, reactjs, grid, position

[9 circles in a 3 x 3 grid with random lines on three of them connecting them to other circles (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfzkH.png)

I'm trying to more of less re-create the image above using react. The circles are div blocks and I have no clue how to go about drawing the lines that "connect" one circle to the other.

I tried using `react-lineto`, but it's simply not rendering anything when I use it. I can use the `hr` tag and use position absolute or something and just play around with where it's placed by toying with top and left props, but I don't think I'd be able to create diagonal lines.

Open to whatever packages or strategies you guys think could help me connect two dots (which are styled div blocks) with a line that could be vertical, horizontal, or diagonal.

Below is what I added to use `react-lineto` that didn't work. Straight from the documentation. I don't care to get `react-lineto` working as much as I just care to be able to accomplish this task in general.

```
<div className="A"></div>
<div className="B"><div/>
<LineTo from="A" to="B" />
```

Comment: Hello, please add the code about what you've tried so that the community can reproduce the problem. Learn how to [provide a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You need to use canvas to draw shapes https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes#drawing_paths